# LSB Steganography - misfunction of decode function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a LSB steganography, for each caracter of a string, I converted it in binary and every bit I put it in red then green then blue pixel. So each caracter takes almost 2 pixels and a half (red and green of the 3rd pixel).

When encoding, it works perfectly but when decoding it, it doesn't work only for the first two caracters.

How can I solve this?

```
def encode_image(img, msg):
"""
mettre les quantites du (r,v,b) dans un tuple
cacher le message sous carateres binaires
"""
#Longueur du message: L
L = len(msg) + 1
# longueur max du message (255 car)
if L > 255:
    print("texte trop long! (ne pas depasser 255 caracteres)")
    return False
if img.mode != 'RGB':
    print("l image doit etre de type RVB")
    return False
# on utilise une copie de l image pour cacher le texte 
encode = img.copy()
row=column=0
colonne, ligne = img.size

r, v, b = img.getpixel((column, row))
encode.putpixel((column, row), (L, v , b))

for c in (msg):
    print ("\n\t\t\t\tCaractèr:\t ", c)
    binary_char = bin(ord(c))[2:]
    if (len(binary_char) != 8):
        difference = 8 - len(binary_char)
        x = 0
        for x in range(0, difference):
            binary_char = "0" + binary_char
    print ("\n\t\t\t\tCaractère binaire:\t ", binary_char)
    i = 0
    pic = 0;
    column+=1
    if(column == colonne):
        row+=1
        column=0
    for char in (binary_char):
        r, v, b = img.getpixel((column, row))
        print("\nRouge=\t",r,"\nVert=\t",v,"\nBleu=\t",b)

        binary_red = bin(r)[2:]
        if (len(binary_red) != 8):
            difference = 8 - len(binary_red)
            x = 0
            for x in range(0, difference):
                binary_red = "0" + binary_red
        binary_blue = bin(b)[2:]
        if (len(binary_blue) != 8):
            difference = 8 - len(binary_blue)
            x = 0
            for x in range(0, difference):
                binary_blue = "0" + binary_blue
        binary_vert = bin(v)[2:]
        if (len(binary_vert) != 8):
            difference = 8 - len(binary_vert)
            x = 0
            for x in range(0, difference):
                binary_vert = "0" + binary_vert
        print("\nBinary Rouge=\t",binary_red,"\nBinary 
Vert=\t",binary_vert,"\nBinary Bleu=\t",binary_blue)

        if( i % 3 == 0):
            new_binary_red = binary_red[:7] + char
            new_red = int(new_binary_red, 2)
            pic+=1
            i+=1
            print("\nNew binary Rouge=\t",new_binary_red)
            print("\nNew Rouge=\t",new_red)
        elif( i % 3 == 1):
            new_binary_vert = binary_vert[:7] + char
            new_vert = int(new_binary_vert, 2)
            pic+=1
            i+=1
            print("\nNew binary Vert=\t",new_binary_vert)
            print("\nNew Vert=\t",new_vert)
        elif( i % 3 == 2):
            new_binary_blue = binary_blue[:7] + char
            new_blue = int(new_binary_blue, 2)
            pic+=1
            i+=1
            print("\nNew binary Bleu=\t",new_binary_blue)
            print("\nNew Bleu=\t",new_blue)

        print("\nPixel=\t",pic,"\nLigne=\t",row,"\nColonne=\t",column)
        if( pic == 3):
            encode.putpixel((column, row), (new_red, new_vert, new_blue))
            pic = 0
            column+=1
            if(column == colonne):
                row+=1
                column = 0
return encode



def decode_image(img):

colonne, ligne = img.size
#print("\nrow:\t", ligne,"\ncolonne:\t",colonne)
i=j=compteur=0
r,v,b = img.getpixel((j,i))
L=r - 1 
msg = ""
c=''

for compteur in range(L):
    pic = 0;
    j+=1
    if(j == colonne):
        i+=1
        j=0
    char_binaire = ""
    taille = len(char_binaire)
    for taille in range(0, 8):
        print("\nrow:\t", i,"\ncolonne:\t",j)
        r,v,b = img.getpixel((j,i))
        print("\nRouge=\t",r,"\nVert=\t",v,"\nBleu=\t",b)
        binary_red = bin(r)[2:]
        if (len(binary_red) != 8):
            difference = 8 - len(binary_red)
            x = 0
            for x in range(0, difference):
                binary_red = "0" + binary_red
        binary_blue = bin(b)[2:]
        if (len(binary_blue) != 8):
            difference = 8 - len(binary_blue)
            x = 0
            for x in range(0, difference):
                binary_blue = "0" + binary_blue
        binary_vert = bin(v)[2:]
        if (len(binary_vert) != 8):
            difference = 8 - len(binary_vert)
            x = 0
            for x in range(0, difference):
                binary_vert = "0" + binary_vert
        print("\nBinary Rouge=\t",binary_red,"\nBinary 
Vert=\t",binary_vert,"\nBinary Bleu=\t",binary_blue)

        if (taille % 3 == 0):
            char_binaire = char_binaire + binary_red[7:]
            pic += 1
        elif (taille % 3 == 1):
            char_binaire = char_binaire + binary_vert[7:]
            pic += 1
        elif (taille % 3 == 2):
            char_binaire = char_binaire + binary_blue[7:]
            pic += 1
        print("\nBinary Caracter=\t",char_binaire)
        print("\nPixel=\t",pic)
        if ( pic == 3):
            pic = 0
            j+=1
            if(j == colonne):
                i+=1
                j = 0
    c = chr(int(char_binaire, 2))
    msg = msg + c
    print("\nCaracter=\t",c,"\nMessage=\t",msg)
return msg

choix=int(input("Choisir : \n 1 => Encoder l'image \n 2 => Decoder l'image 
\n 99 => Quitter \n Votre choix: \t"))

while( choix != 99):
    if choix == 1:
    # vous pouvez donner le chemin complet de l image
    fichier_original_image=input("Donnez le chemin complet de l'image à 
crypter:\t")
    img = Image.open(fichier_original_image)
    # le mode de l image doit etre 'RVB'


    # creer un nouveau document pour l image modifiee/codee
    pos1 = fichier_original_image.rfind('\\')+1
    pos2 = fichier_original_image.rfind('.')
    pos2 = pos2 + len('.bmp')
    image_name = fichier_original_image[pos1:pos2]
    image_encode = "enc_" + image_name
    chemin_image = fichier_original_image[:pos1]+image_encode


    # on ne depasse pas 255 caracteres
    secret_msg = input("Donnez le message à cacher: \t")

    img_encode = encode_image(img, secret_msg)
    if img_encode:
        # save the image with the hidden text
        img_encode.save(chemin_image)
        print("{} saved!".format(image_encode))

        # l image sauvegardee dans le chemin du programme

        import os
        os.system('cygwin' + image_encode)

elif choix == 2:

    # retourner le message secret
    chemin = input("Donnez le chemin complet de l'image à decrypter: ")
    encode_img = Image.open(chemin)
    hidden_text = decode_image(encode_img)

    print("Texte caché:\n{}".format(hidden_text))

    choix=int(input("Choisir : \n 1 => Encoder l'image \n 2 => Decoder l'image \n 99 => Quitter \n Votre choix: \t"))
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work with the first two characters? Can you provide an example of input/output to demonstrates the error? You can also make it easier for us to read your code by putting the repetitive parts in functions so it's shorter. Or you can use the following logic to get rid of extraneous code. `binary_color = bin(color)[2:]; binary_color = binary_color[:-1] + char` to embed and `char_binaire = char_binaire + color[-1]` to extract. No padding to length 8 is necessary.